# How to select text of tag a

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have tag `a`

```
<a href="mailto:some@mail.com">some@mail.com</a>
```

and I cannot select its text. It starts to drag, I've tried to use

```
-webkit-user-drag: none;
```

Tag is not dragged but text is still unselectable.

http://jsfiddle.net/ykHH5/8/

Comment: Actually you can select it. It's just that the large amount of padding means you have to drag from a strange starting position because you are increasing the bounding box of the element http://jsfiddle.net/ykHH5/10/

Comment: You can select it, you just need to start dragging from the edge of the element, if you want to be able to select from the text edge, then you could wrap it in a `span`, and add the padding to the `span` element - http://jsfiddle.net/ykHH5/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it's a hyperlink. The text inside it is perfectly selectable if you click outside and drag into it. If you click inside for selecting, it immediately starts doing what it'd do. (*for e.g., in my system it opens the mail application.*)

My suggestion should be to wrap it inside a `<div>` if you don't need the entire area to be clickable

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykHH5/15/)

Comment: That'e entirely logical... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can still select the text. Get off the padding class in your fiddle. Give some wrapper div  for your anchor tag.  Here is a fiddle,

```
<b>  http://jsfiddle.net/ykHH5/12</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop its dragging by giving attribute `draggable="false"` Rest behavior will be same

```
<a href="mailto:some@mail.com" draggable="false">some@mail.com</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ykHH5/14/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master in html but following code helps you to achieve what you want:

```
<div class="block"><a href="mailto:some@mail.com">some@mail.com</a></div>

a{color: white;}

.block{
    display: inline-block;
    background: black;
    padding: 50px 100px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius:0px;
}
```